# Lua nested tables, table.insert function

Tags: lua

i started learning lua and now i'm trying to deal with nested tables.

Basically i want to create a kind of local "database" using json interaction with lua (i found out that was the best thing to store my values)...

what i supposed to do is to scan all members inside a chatgroup (i'm using an unofficial telegram api) and store some values inside a table. I was able to retrieve all datas needed, so here's the structure declared in main function:

```
local dbs = load_data("./data/database.json")

dbs[tostring(msg.to.id)] = {
        gr_name = {},
        timestamp = "",
        user = {               --user changes into user ids
            us_name = {},
            us_nickname = {},
            us_role = ""
        },
    }
```

where msg.to.id contains a valid number. This is what i tried to do:

```
dbs[tostring(id)]['users'][tostring(v.peer_id)]['us_nickname'] = v.username
```

this one works but this one:

```
dbs[tostring(id)]['users'][tostring(v.peer_id)] = table.insert(us_name,v.print_name)
```

(id is a correct number and matches with first field, same as all values passed like v.peer_id and v.print_name so those are not the problem)

gives error "table expected"... i'm pretty sure i have totally no idea of how to insert an element in such a table like mine.

Can anyone of you be so kind to help me? I hope to be clear enough explaining my issue.

Thanks in advance to everyone :)

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. `table.insert` is for arrays, and you don't have one. Are you trying to create a table to add to `users`?

Comment: `table.insert` inserts a value into a table and doesn't return anything.

Comment: a single user can change names so i want to store the new value without overwrite it in field us_names... i thought the best way was to declare an array of us_names ad to use table.insert in that field to store without overwrting previous value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add new user name to an existing user you probably want to insert it into the sub-table like this:

```
table.insert(dbs[tostring(id)]['users'][tostring(v.peer_id)].us_name, v.print_name)
```

Comment: yea solved thanks :) i found out that in fact table.insert does not need to be assigned like i did, using equals.